# Replace text in imported Less file

Tags: css, less

I am using Less and I'm importing CSS from an external library:

```
@import '../../../theme.css';
```

Is there any way to process this imported file in Less and replace some text (like colors)?

I took a look at the [replace function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-replace), but I didn't find a way to use it on an imported file.

```
// I am looking for something like this
replace(@importedCss, '#111111', '#555555');
```